# Meteor with Kloudless service

Tags: javascript, meteor, kloudless

I am following a jsfiddle example here where Kloudless API was used. link [Kloudless API in Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/pseudonumos/PB565/embedded/)

Using the code below with the jsfiddle code I place it on my template rendered but sadly it did not work

```
Template.kloudless.rendered = function() {
     var explorer = window.Kloudless.explorer({
         app_id: 'iCZ_ICMy43H0NSoz0QbLvmyjzCHf2frAOPaBfWVgh9_vrFIM',
         multiselect: true,
         computer: true
     });

    explorer.on('success', function(files) {
        $("#file-info > pre").replaceWith('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(files, null, 2) + '</pre>');
    });

    explorer.choosify($('#chooser'));

    var files = [{
        url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static-assets.kloudless.com/static/logo_white.png",
        name: "kloudless-logo.png"
    }];

    explorer.savify($("#saver"), files);
}
```

If I placed the the code as shown below it will work. Is there a way to write the code in a more Meteor way, like the following code?

```
<header> 
    <title>myapp</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var explorer = window.Kloudless.explorer({
            app_id: 'iCZ_ICMy43H0NSoz0QbLvmyjzCHf2frAOPaBfWVgh9_vrFIM',
            multiselect: true,
            computer: true
        });

        explorer.on('success', function(files) {
            $("#file-info > pre").replaceWith('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(files, null, 2) + '</pre>');
        });

        explorer.choosify($('#chooser'));

        var files = [{
            url: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/static-assets.kloudless.com/static/logo_white.png",
            name: "kloudless-logo.png"
        }];

        explorer.savify($("#saver"), files);
    </script>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is npm package [kloudless-meteor](https://www.npmjs.org/package/kloudless-meteor).

You can use it with meteor. 
Instruction for `meteor > 0.9.0`:

First add [npm](http://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm) package:

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

Note npm packages can be used only on server side.

Create `packages.json` file :

```
{
  "kloudless-meteor":"0.0.1"
}
```

Then start using it on `server side` like this:

```
var kloudless = Meteor.npmRequire('kloudless')('your-api-key-here');
```

**[Documentation](https://developers.kloudless.com/docs)**

```
 API methods are called in the scheme of... 
 kloudless.<resource>.<method>(<data-json>, <callback>);
```

#### Side note

If you want to upload files with `kloudless` to cloud provider ( amazon, rackspace, etc ) then first you need to upload from client to server. I recommend to do that using `https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS`

Comment: I saw the NPM [link] (https://www.npmjs.org/package/kloudless-meteor) but does not know about the meteor add meteorhacks:npm. This is a lot better. Where should the {var kloudless = require('kloudless')('your-api-key-here');} be saved? In client or server folder?